# Придаточное или цельное по смыслу выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, придаточное-предложение, цельное-выражение

> Его останавливают: к этим пока нельзя, их неделю как из Белого моря
>   доставили. С ними только общаться начинают. Вот дежурят рядышком с
>   ними сутками – проверяют, чтобы адаптация шла как нужно.

"Идти как нужно" - цельное?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что "цельность" всегда учитывает и глагол?

Comment: См. подобный случай: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431913/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f

Comment: М_Г, это совсем не мой случай, там оборот с союзом "как" входит в состав сказуемого.

Comment: Согласен. Как пояснила @Sibylla, здесь предикативная основа - "адаптация шла", а оборот "как нужно" является обстоятельством

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это цельное по смыслу выражение:
Вот дежурят рядышком с ними сутками – проверяют, чтобы адаптация шла **как нужно**.

**Пояснение**

Такие выражения имеют значение **одного слова** (обстоятельства):
*...чтобы адаптация шла **правильно (нужным образом)**.*

[Розенталь: § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.
Перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний запятая не ставится: **выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно).**

Comment: Ссылка не туда ведет.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что является сказуемым: "шла" или "шла как нужно". Есть ли разница между "шла как нужно" и "буду  как папа" из другого вопроса (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431913/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Comment: 1) проверяют, чтобы адаптация шла /как нужно. Здесь предикативная основа "адаптация шла", оборот является обстоятельством. 2) Буду как папа. Здесь оборот составляет именную часть сказуемого, буду - это связка.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере "как нужно" входит в состав придаточного предложение, но само не образует придаточное. *Шла как нужно* (как полагается, как надо).

Comment: Серж! А почему ответ отмечен как «низкокачественный»?

Comment: @ shampar, модераторы будут знать. Я не знаю.