# Буду как папа. Это сравнение, нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Буду как папа.* Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна: здесь оборот с союзом *как* входит в состав сказуемого, причём без этого оборота предложение не несёт какого-либо законченного смысла.

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

(см. случай 3 без запятой)