# Придаточные или цельные по смыслу выражения? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, придаточное-предложение, цельное-выражение

Похожие вопросы:
[Придаточное или цельное по смыслу выражение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431905/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%E2%80%91%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5); [“Проси у меня (,) чего хочешь” — цельное по смыслу выражение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437845/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

*Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать, **с кем надо** договориться и **куда нужно** пролезть.*

**Вопрос**. Подходят ли выделенные обороты под розенталевское правило о цельных по смыслу выражениях: первый оборот заменяется на дополнение "с нужными людьми", второй оборот — на обстоятельство "в нужные места", или же обороты образуют придаточную часть — изъяснительную и дополнительную (изъяснительную) соответственно? Что насчёт их обособления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ из комментария Sharon**

*Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнАть, с кем надо договорИться и куда нужно пролЕзть*.

При таком прочтении всё оформлено верно. Устный вариант вполне себе хорош, к нему нет вопросов. Эти именно устойчивые обороты, которые не требуют обособления.

Comment: Всё-таки можно принять свой ответ. Круто! Это точно достойно лайка (давно задавался этим вопросом, но нигде не встречал, а у Sharon не получилось это сделать). Но смотрю, что 15 баллов не дали. || А порядка c двусмысленностью (стилистической ошибкой - а тут явное преимущество у неверного варианта) нужно стараться избегать.

Comment: В справке нашёл, что "принять свой ответ можно через 48 часов после его публикации". А у вас сразу получилось.

Comment: @oleedd Значит я хакнул Stack Exchange:)

Comment: )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 3):

(1) ***Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать: с кем надо договориться и куда нужно пролезть*** (двоеточие в БСП при наличии обобщающего местоимения).

(2) ***Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете  разузнать, с кем надо договориться и куда нужно пролезть***.

Предложение (2) — СПП с **двумя явными однородными изъяснительными придаточными**, никаких устойчивых выражений здесь нет.

Изъяснительные придаточные вообще занимают **позицию дополнения**, поэтому  для них можно всегда придумать какую-то замену. Но такое формальное решение не подойдет.

Устойчивый оборот **должен по интонации и структуре занимать позицию одного слова.** Достаточно одного распространителя, и уже потребуется  обособления оборота в качестве придаточного предложения, так как будет другая расстановка логических ударений. **Даже один и тот же оборот в разных предложениях может обособляться или нет.**

Примеры:

(1) ***Ты ему позвонИ, разузнай что нАдо, потом мне расскажешь***. (Ударение падает только на оборот, паузы нет).

(2) ***Ты позвонИ, разузнАй, что ему нАдо, потом мне расскажешь.***(Ударение падает  и на оборот,  и на сказуемое, пауза делается).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных словосочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологизма, то **оно может образовать придаточную часть** (обычно неполное предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно — ‘везде’; Поставить, где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания — ‘где это нужно’.

Comment: Удивительно, насколько несовершенной может быть письменная речь, когда настолько по-разному можно понять одно и то же предложение, если по-разному расставить фразовые ударения. ***Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнАть, с кем нАдо договорИться и куда нУжно пролЕзть***. После «разузнать» нет двоеточия или тире, а значит, и длинной паузы. Следовательно, здесь нет однородных придаточных и БСП с обобщающим местоимением — здесь просто однородные члены. «Всё разузнать» по смыслу само по себе.

Answer (score 0):

Не подходит. Это придаточное.

Главная причина в том, что несколько логических ударений: *вы успеваете вс**Ё** разузнать, с кем надо договор**И**ться и куда нужно прол**Е**зть*.

Перед "*с кем надо*" правильнее поставить двоеточие: там перечисляется, что именно разузнать, и присутствует общее слово "всё".

Но так (с одним ударением) подходит: *вы успеете разузнать что н**У**жно* и...

Анализ примеров Розенталя:

В таких случаях "вопросительные" местоимения заменяют "ответные" и они сопоставимы (*тогда/когда; то/что; того/чего; тем/чем; там/где, так/как и т.п.*):
*Делайте (то,) что хотите.* || Заменяет "то".
*Говорит об этом (там,) где только может.

Не лезть (туда,) куда не следует.

Поживиться (тем,) чем можно.

Наглядишься, наслушаешься ты здесь (того,) чего не надо.

Здесь всегда можно достать (то,) что понадобится.

Говорите (так,) как есть на самом деле.

Приглашу к себе (того,) кого пожелаю.

Живу (там,) где придётся.*

Comment: Вы успеваете разУзнать,  что нУжно.  В таком предложении оборот,  скорее всего, будет обособляться.  Сравнить: Вы узнаёте что нУжно  и доклАдываете мне.

Comment: Можно обособлять, а можно и нет. Ну как-то оно не очень с двумя ударениями в таком коротком варианте. Просто хотел переделать так, чтобы можно было не ставить запятую (сохраняя оригинальные слова).

Comment: Удивительно, насколько несовершенной может быть письменная речь, когда настолько по-разному можно понять одно и то же предложение, если по-разному расставить фразовые ударения. ***Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнАть, с кем нАдо договорИться и куда нУжно пролЕзть***. После «разузнать» нет двоеточия или тире, а значит, и длинной паузы. Следовательно, здесь нет однородных придаточных и БСП с обобщающим местоимением — здесь просто однородные члены. «Всё разузнать» по смыслу само по себе.

Comment: oleedd,  ваш короткий вариант не должен висеть в воздухе, эту структуру нужно поместить в конкретное предложение. Вот тогда будет ясна расстановка логических ударений в нем, тогда и вывод нужно делать. Эта неопределенность (можно ставить, можно нет) не должна присутствовать при анализе, он в этом случае кажется неубедительным. Приводите два примера: с запятой и без запятой. Это должны быть разные по структуре примеры. (В моем примере присутствуют однородные члены,  вот они и определяют, где ставится ударение, потому что должны выделяться этим ударением).

Comment: Василий Ефименко: 1) Всё - это подлежащее в БСП, а не "само по себе". 2) СПП в данном случае состоит из двух интонационных фраз, так выражаются временные отношения между предложениями (1) и (2+3), поэтому и паузы нет. 3) Из интонационного анализа не следует напрямую анализ грамматический, поэтому ваше "следовательно" мне представляется неубедительным. 4) Так что всё здесь не просто.

Comment: Так просто пишу, что короткий пример **подходит**, чтобы не ставить запятую. А пример с запятой - само предложение из вопроса. || Вариант СПП в связке с "всё" всё-таки возможен, хоть и не очевиден. Соответственно, и интонация будет другая. *Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать (о том), с кем надо договориться и куда нужно пролезть.* Пропущен элемент "о том", который пропускать нежелательно. В такой интерпретации слово "всё" вообще нельзя подчёркивать.

Comment: @Sharon **Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать, с нужными людьми договориться и в нужные места пролезть.** Вот такой здесь смысл, коллеги! :)

Comment: @Sharon "С кем надо договориться" и "куда нужна пролезть" НЕ поясняет местоимение "всё".

Comment: @Василий Ефименко  Уважаемый коллега! Если два человека не поняли ваш текст, то это означает, что его могут не понять и другие читатели, а это расценивается как  стилистическая неточность.  После глагола разузнать следует однородный член, который можно принять за придаточное предложение, так как перед находится местоимение "с кем", Это относится и ко второму однородному члену с местоимением  "куда". Соответственно, предложение желательно отредактировать: семантическая  и грамматическая неясность является существенным недостатком текста.

Comment: @Sharon Как там может быть придаточное изъяснительное, если у "разузнать" уже есть дополнение "всё"? **Изъяснять нечего**. Насчёт БСП: там нет ни двоеточия, ни тире — интонация явно перечислительная. Да, запятая может являться более "мягким" знаком перед пояснением, но это нельзя назвать стандартным вариантом.

Comment: @Василий Ефименко Это вы так считаете, а читателю что делать? При беглом просмотре он считывает опорные слова: "всё", которое ему кажется обобщающим словом;  местоимения, которые имитируют союзные слова. Бедный читатель! Он останавливается и пытается разобраться в грамматике: то ли здесь у автора ошибка, то ли он что-то недопонял. А ему-то хочется бегло прочитать текст (желательно по диагонали), а не спотыкаться на  отдельных словах и фразах. Он начинает нервничать и сердиться, а виноват кто? Да кто угодно, только не уважаемый автор.

Comment: И по поводу перечислительной интонации. Как догадаться, что она именно перечислительная, ведь у интонации нет письменного обозначения. Явной она становится только в устной речи.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, согласен: допущение возможности иного понимания — недочёт автора. Давайте абстрагируемся от этого и ответим на вопрос, являются ли "с кем надо" и "куда нужно" цельными по смыслу выражениями в моём варианте и надо ли их обособлять, например ставить после них тире?

Comment: Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнАть, с кем надо договорИться и куда нужно пролЕзть. При таком прочтении всё оформлено верно. Устный вариант вполне себе хорош, к нему нет вопросов. Эти именно устойчивые обороты, которые не требуют обособления.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко При таком смысле должен быть другой порядок слов: *Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать, договориться (с тем,) с кем надо и пролезть (туда,) куда нужно.* Это цельные выражения - запятые не нужны, и стилистически звучит гораздо лучше. В изначальном порядке вопросительная интонация - оно совсем не воспринимается в данном смысле.

Comment: Почему вы так думаете? Наоборот, «всё разузнать» — дополнение стоит перед сказуемым, так что при следующих сказуемых дополнению также неплохо бы стоять в такой же позиции: "с кем надо договориться», "куда нужно пролезть".

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко Потому что в вашем порядке двусмысленность (и сначала [когда давал ответ] понял неверно): *Пока остальные плывут по течению, вы успеваете всё разузнать, (а именно то) с кем надо договориться и куда нужно пролезть.*

Answer (score -1):

> Вопрос. Подходят ли выделенные обороты под розенталевское правило о
>   цельных по смыслу выражениях:

Не знаю наверняка, о каком правиле вы говорите, но тут однозначно никаких обобых правил не требуется. Куда и кому - союзные слова.

> первый оборот заменяется на дополнение "с нужными людьми", второй
>   оборот — на обстоятельство "в нужные места",

А зачем заменять? Оставтье их в покое.

> или же обороты образуют придаточную часть — изъяснительную и
>   дополнительную (изъяснительную) соответственно? Что насчёт их
>   обособления?

Образуют. Очень трудно придумать другую роль для "пролезть" и "договориться". 
Цельные по смыслу выражения тпкие, которые не позволяют без некоторой потери смысла и связности заменить в себе отдельные слова. Эти выражения - позволяют.

Comment: Тогда какой ваш вариант пунктуации в данном предложении?